# Parsing JSON error object containing an array with Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

```
public class Restaurants1
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string address { get; set; }
            public string contact { get; set; }
            public string links { get; set; }
            public string about { get; set; }
            public string info { get; set; }
            public string image { get; set; }
            public string lat { get; set; }
            public string lng { get; set; }
            public string currency { get; set; }
            public string minprice { get; set; }
            public string maxprice { get; set; }
            public string facility { get; set; }
            public string keywords { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
            public string review_count { get; set; }
            public string distance { get; set; }
            public string menu_image { get; set; }
            public string menu_resizead { get; set; }
        }
    public class Restaurants2
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string contact { get; set; }
        public string links { get; set; }
        public string about { get; set; }
        public string info { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }
        public string lat { get; set; }
        public string lng { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public string minprice { get; set; }
        public string maxprice { get; set; }
        public string facility { get; set; }
        public string keywords { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string review_count { get; set; }
        public string distance { get; set; }
        public string menu_image { get; set; }
        public string menu_resizead { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public List<Restaurants1> restaurants1 { get; set; }
        public List<Restaurants2> restaurants2 { get; set; }
        public bool no_featured { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string status { get; set; }
        public Result result { get; set; }
    }

       var url = e.UserState as Uri;
       RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result); 
                  MessageBox.Show("success");

RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result) is Error
like this :
```

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string)'
>   has some invalid
>   arguments E:\parsingjson\parsingjson\MainPage.xaml.cs 103 30  parsingjson

why? 
and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Post a snippet of your json containing at least one record. are you sure e.Result is of a string Type? If it is a stream then you would need to read the stream into a string using a StreamReader for the Json Deserializer to work.